# AjaxControlToolkit PieChart not showing any data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to implement a simple AjaxControlToolkit PieChart, but whatever data I'm using the page looks like this, on Chrome or IE 11 and IE 10:

[image]

Here is my simple code:

```
<asp:piechart id="PieChart1" runat="server" backcolor="#993333" bordercolor="#660033"
        borderstyle="Solid" forecolor="White" height="349px" width="320px" charttitle="Country Population"
        charttitlecolor="Blue">        
    <PieChartValues>    
        <asp:PieChartValue Category="India" Data="1000" PieChartValueColor="green" PieChartValueStrokeColor="white" />        
        <asp:PieChartValue Category="US" Data="3000" PieChartValueColor="blue" PieChartValueStrokeColor="black" />      
        <asp:PieChartValue Category="China" Data="6000" PieChartValueColor="pink"  PieChartValueStrokeColor="red" />    
        <asp:PieChartValue Category="Australia" Data="7000" PieChartValueColor="yellow" PieChartValueStrokeColor="blue" />        
    </PieChartValues>     
</asp:piechart>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/955025/ajax-pie-chart/

Comment: Followed these steps EXACTLY but I get no data shown, only a blank element.